# Why Log4j2 does not allow to reconfigure package logger more than once

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am using Log4j2 in my application. We have a requirement to provide a facility to reconfigure logging at runtime to aid application debugging. E.g., we should be able to add a new package-level logger, a class-level logger etc. at the runtime. The problem statement that I am putting here is for package-level logger configuration. Please check the codes below:

**LogConfigurer.java**

```
public class LogConfigurer {
  public static void addPackageLogger(final String packageName, final Level level) {
    final LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();

    final Appender appender = configuration.getAppender("RollingRandomAccessFile");
    final LoggerConfig loggerConfig = new LoggerConfig(packageName, level, false);
    loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, level, null);
    configuration.addLogger(packageName, loggerConfig);
    context.updateLoggers();
  }
}
```

**PackageLoggingMock.java** (A sample class)

```
public class PackageLoggingMock {
  // Logger
  private final static org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(PackageLoggingMock.class);

  public void mockMethod(final String msg) {
    logger.debug("[PackageLoggingMock] Debug statement...{}", msg);
    logger.info("[PackageLoggingMock] Info statement...{}", msg);
    logger.warn("[PackageLoggingMock] Warn statement...{}", msg);
    logger.error("[PackageLoggingMock] Error statement...{}", msg);
  }
}
```

**PackageLoggingDemo.java**

```
public class PackageLoggingDemo {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final PackageLoggingMock mock = new PackageLoggingMock();

    // Running with default settings provided in log4j2.xml
    mock.mockMethod("BEFORE");

    // Reset log level of package "com.logging.demo" to DEBUG
    try {
      LogConfigurer.addPackageLogger("com.logging.demo", Level.DEBUG);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // After resetting to DEBUG level
    mock.mockMethod("AFTER SETTING TO DEBUG");

    // Reset log level of package "com.logging.demo" to INFO
    try {
      LogConfigurer.addPackageLogger("com.logging.demo", Level.INFO);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // After resetting to DEBUG level
    mock.mockMethod("AFTER SETTING TO INFO");
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[PackageLoggingMock] Error statement...BEFORE
[PackageLoggingMock] Debug statement...AFTER SETTING TO DEBUG
[PackageLoggingMock] Info statement...AFTER SETTING TO DEBUG
[PackageLoggingMock] Warn statement...AFTER SETTING TO DEBUG
[PackageLoggingMock] Error statement...AFTER SETTING TO DEBUG
[PackageLoggingMock] Debug statement...AFTER SETTING TO INFO
[PackageLoggingMock] Info statement...AFTER SETTING TO INFO
[PackageLoggingMock] Warn statement...AFTER SETTING TO INFO
[PackageLoggingMock] Error statement...AFTER SETTING TO INFO
```

It still prints the `DEBUG` statement even after the level has been reconfigured to `INFO`.

I am not able to understand this behavior; is it expected?

As a workaround, after first reconfigure (to level `DEBUG`), I tried to reset the logger to have original config and then applied `INFO` level programmatically and it worked.

Is there a way to configure log levels multiple times without resetting the log?

Comment: You are just **adding**. In order to change, you'll have to remove the old config for that package and add the new one.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I added `configuration.removeLogger(packageName);` and then `configuration.addLogger(packageName, loggerConfig);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just adding. In order to change, you'll have to remove the old config for that package and add the new one.

Following this hint, OP used

```
configuration.removeLogger(packageName);
configuration.addLogger(packageName, loggerConfig);
```

to solve the issue.